# Android application with baselineprofile macro benchmark is failing with profileinstaller library issue

Tags: android, performance, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark, compilationmode

I am trying to improve performance for my application by trying baseprofile but unable to run it. Configured the project with gradle 8.2 and

```
'androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.1'
'androidx.benchmark:benchmark-macro-junit4:1.2.2'
```

I was able to generate *baseline-prof.txt* using emulator but could not test performance by running the benchmark snippet

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class StartupBenchmarks {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = MacrobenchmarkRule()

    @Test
    fun startupCompilationNone() =
        benchmark(CompilationMode.None())

    @Test
    fun startupCompilationBaselineProfiles() =
        benchmark(CompilationMode.Partial(BaselineProfileMode.Require))

    private fun benchmark(compilationMode: CompilationMode) {
        rule.measureRepeated(
            packageName = "com.example.android",
            metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
            compilationMode = compilationMode,
            startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
            iterations = 1,
            setupBlock = {
                pressHome()
            },
            measureBlock = {
                startActivityAndWait()
                device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("Exit")),10_000)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Getting the below errors for the benchmark tests

**startupCompilationNone()**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The baseline profile install broadcast was not received. This most likely means that the profileinstaller library is missing from the target apk.
```

**startupCompilationBaselineProfiles()**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DROP_SHADER_CACHE broadcast was not received. This most likely means that the `androidx.profileinstaller` library used by the target apk is old. Please use `1.3.0-alpha02` or newer. For more information refer to the release notes at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/profileinstaller.
```

Not sure what is going wrong, I am trying with all the latest available libs and also tested with multiple devices Pixel, motoE, OnePlus with disabling battery optimization.

Any direction of help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was unrelated to the above error. The profileinstaller issue getting in Test results tab was misleading. Found there was a proguard TypeToken issue in gson. Adding the below lines in progaurd fixed the issue

```
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type
```

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer for the purposes of a question seeker. Thanks! :)