Error: The DROP_SHADER_CACHE broadcast was not received when adding Baseline Profile in Android App
I am trying to add a baseline profile for an Android app. I have primarily used the Google Android documentation and [this video][https://youtu.be/m7oRRdud-mY?si=0vrqtY5pYg-61Fue] to create a new benchmark module and associated setup to add the baseline profile.
I have tried various solutions present on the internet for this issue:
•   [Question with similar issue][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77732757/android-application-with-baselineprofile-macro-benchmark-is-failing-with-profile]
•   [Google Issue Tracker about the same issue and the solution mentioned][https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/325502725]
•   [Another Google issue link I referred][https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258619948]
I am getting the following error when I run the test on the device on which I have installed this benchmark build:
I am currently using version 1.4.1 of androidx.profileinstaller.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DROP_SHADER_CACHE broadcast was not received. This most likely means that the `androidx.profileinstaller` library used by the target apk is old. Please use `1.3.0-alpha02` or newer. For more information refer to the release notes at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/profileinstaller.
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkScope.dropShaderCache(MacrobenchmarkScope.kt:300)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:454)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:436)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:265)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:255)
at androidx.benchmark.perfetto.PerfettoTraceProcessor$Companion.runServer(PerfettoTraceProcessor.kt:105)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmark(Macrobenchmark.kt:255)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode(Macrobenchmark.kt:436)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule.measureRepeated(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:107)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule.measureRepeated$default(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:97)
at StartupBenchmark.startup(StartupBenchmark.kt:15)

